# How do I create a post to my Opportunity feed via REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, opportunity, feeditem, chatter-feed-tracking

How can I create post to an Opportunity's feed via the REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this endpoint url

```
/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/FeedItem
```

And use POST method and pass the body

```
{
"ParentId":  "0069000000K8YjL",
"Body" : "hello there",
"type" : "TextPost",
"Title" : "New Post"
}
```

[image]

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Chatter REST API. (You'll need to use it if you want to include @mentions, which aren't supported when inserting FeedItem sObjects. Here's the [example from the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_item.htm).)